# How can I propagate properties into a nested sql fragment?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I have an `sql` looks like this.

```xml
<sql name="level1">
  ${alias}some AS ${prefix}some
</sql>
```

Now I want to nest above fragment into another fragment while propagating those two properties.

```xml
<sql name="level2">
  ${alias}other AS ${prefix}other,
  <include refid="level1">
    <property name="alias" value="${alias}"/> <!-- will this "${alias}" work? -->
    <property name="prefix" value="${prefix}"/>  <!-- will this "${prefix}" work? -->
  </include>
</sql>
```

My apologies, I should've tried for myself and saw what happened. But I'm working on a remote site and the testing environment is not complete.

Comment: It should work (if I understand correctly).